# Foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Table A: Author Information

```
CREATE TABLE TableA (
    AuthorLastName VARCHAR(255),
    AuthorFirstName VARCHAR(255),
    BookTitle VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (AuthorLastName, AuthorFirstName, BookTitle)
);
```

Table B: Book Information

```
CREATE TABLE TableB (
    BookTitle VARCHAR(255),
    Subject VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (BookTitle, Subject),
    FOREIGN KEY (BookTitle) REFERENCES TableA(BookTitle)
);
```

Table C: Subject and Collection/Location

```
CREATE TABLE TableC (
    Subject VARCHAR(255),
    CollectionorLocation VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (Subject, CollectionorLocation),
    FOREIGN KEY (Subject) REFERENCES TableB(Subject)
);
```

Table D: Collection/Location and Building

```
CREATE TABLE TableD (
    CollectionorLocation VARCHAR(255),
    Building VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (CollectionorLocation, Building),
    FOREIGN KEY (CollectionorLocation) REFERENCES TableC(CollectionorLocation)
);
```

> ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table `dbms_assignment`.`tableb` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
> In TableB,TableC and TableD

Comment: Provide **COMPLETE** `CREATE TABLE` scripts. Now even `CREATE TABLE TableB ..` must fail due to the index absence.. Also - provide complete `SHOW CREATE TABLE ..` output for tables A-C when `CREATE TABLE TableD ..` fails.

Comment: Are you assuming two books with the same title will have the same subject?  Note that `PRIMARY KEY` (in MySQL and MariaDB) implies UNIQUE.  Rethink the structure.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the missing indexes on the referenced columns.

When dealing with foreign keys always see

- [Conditions and Restrictions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html#foreign-key-restrictions)

---

Apply the following changes to fix your issue

```
alter table TableA add index BookTitle(BookTitle);
alter table TableB add index Subject(Subject);
alter table TableC add index CollectionorLocation(CollectionorLocation);
```

[See working example](https://dbfiddle.uk/Tolz8yIM)

Comment: The error reports that the problem in question is not the index absence problem. I think that OP problem is charset/collation one...

Answer (score 0):

A foreign key should reference the *whole* set of columns in the primary key of the referenced table. You are breaking that rule several times.

For example, TableA has a primary key `(AuthorLastName, AuthorFirstName, BookTitle)`. That's three columns. This table can have only one row for a given combination of values in those three columns, but multiple rows can have the same value in any one or two of those columns.

The foreign key in TableB references one of those three columns, `BookTitle`. This means a row in TableB might reference multiple rows in TableA, which is not a proper foreign key. A foreign key should reference exactly one row in the referenced table.

Therefore a foreign key should have the same number of columns as the primary key in the table it references. That's the only way it can be assured to reference exactly one row in that table.

The same mistake is in TableC, referencing part of the primary key of TableB.

The same mistake is in TableD, referencing part of the primary key of TableC.

Besides that, I think your data modeling has other problems. Why would BookTitle be part of the primary key of author information? I suspect you are unaware of how to implement many-to-many relationships in SQL.

Say you have a table for author information and a table for book information. But an author can write many books, and some books have multiple authors, right? So it's a many-to-many relationship.

A many-to-many relationship in SQL requires two tables for the entities, an a third table, so each pairing (in this case one author and one book) can be represented by a row in the intersection table. There can be multiple rows in the intersection table for each auther, and there can also be multiple rows for each book.

```
CREATE TABLE Authors (
    AuthorLastName VARCHAR(255),
    AuthorFirstName VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (AuthorLastName, AuthorFirstName)
);

CREATE TABLE Books (
    BookTitle VARCHAR(255),
    Subject VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (BookTitle)
);

CREATE TABLE AuthorBookIntersection (
    AuthorLastName VARCHAR(255),
    AuthorFirstName VARCHAR(255),
    BookTitle VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (AuthorLastName, AuthorFirstName, BookTitle),
    FOREIGN KEY (AuthorLastName, AuthorFirstName)
      REFERENCES Authors(AuthorLastName, AuthorFirstName),
    FOREIGN KEY (BookTitle) REFERENCES Books(BookTitle)
);
```

In each of the foreign keys, the number of columns must match the number of columns of the primary key in the table it references. Two columns for Authors, and one column for Books.

Similar changes can fix your other table relationships.

You may like to read the chapters on foreign keys and data normal forms in my book, [SQL Antipatterns, Volume 1
Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming](https://pragprog.com/titles/bksap1/sql-antipatterns-volume-1/).